# To Split Result About Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

[have a problem about red arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meNkP.png)

[this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxjEM.png)

I want to use jsoup to get creator names.
the sencond image is my result.

```
bean.setmPaperSubTitle(e.select(".record-subtitle").text());
```

but I want to have a result like

```
"蒋挺宇 王鹏 杨述 褥震 董渊 王生原 嵇智源" (have a blank between them).
```

my English is not good :(

Comment: Next time post the code directly in your question. Don't make a screen capture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I want to have a result like
>
> ```
> "蒋挺宇 王鹏 杨述 褥震 董渊 王生原 嵇智源" (have a blank between them).
> ```

What you can do is to loop over the elements one by one. When you hit the anchors with the `creator` class, add a space after them.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String suffix;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(Element e : e.select(".record-subtitle > *")) {
    if ( (e.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("a")) && (e.hasClass("creator")) ) {
       suffix = " ";
    } else {
       suffix = "";
    }

    sb.append(e.text()).append(suffix);
}

bean.setmPaperSubTitle(sb.toString().trim());
```